# looking for cursor replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `#TblFinal` and `#TblData`.. I need to compare #`TblData` data with"#`TblFinal` based on unique key `F_U_KEY vs D_U_KEY.`

1. if #`TblData` data for a unique key is not exist in #`TblFinal`, then #`TblData` data record will insert into #`TblFinal` table. `F_COUNTER` will be 1 (default) and `F_IS_CLEAR` is 0 default
2. if #`TblData` data for a unique key is exist in #`TblFinal`, then first we get key `F_ID` from #`TblFinal`

**case A:** if D_SEV_ID of table "#TblData" is not equal to -11

then need to update "F_COUNTER" for table "#TblFinal" for "F_ID"

**case B:** if D_SEV_ID of table "#TblData" is equal to -11

then new entry for D_SEV_ID = -11 and F_IS_CLEAR =1 for "F_ID"

Here is the cursor I wrote, need some optimized solution as my actual #`TblFinal` having huge data and data compare table "#TblData" always have 100 records to compare.

```
CREATE TABLE #TblFinal
(F_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), F_VAL NVARCHAR(20), F_SEV_ID INT, F_U_KEY NVARCHAR(200), F_COUNTER INT DEFAULT(1), F_IS_CLEAR BIT DEFAULT(0))


CREATE TABLE #TblData
(D_ID INT, D_VAL NVARCHAR(20), D_SEV_ID INT, D_U_KEY NVARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO #TblData VALUES(1, 'test 1', 2, '1:100002135::::15124:9334'),     (2, 'test 1', 2, '1:100002135::::15124:9334'),
(3, 'test', -11, '1:100002135::::15124:9334'), (4, 'test 1', 2, '1:100002135::::15124:9334'), (5, 'test 1', 2, '1:1024:9334')


DECLARE @D_ID INT
DECLARE @D_SEV_ID INT
DECLARE @D_U_KEY NVARCHAR(200)

DECLARE A_CUR CURSOR FOR  
SELECT D_ID, D_SEV_ID, D_U_KEY FROM #TblData ORDER BY D_ID ASC
OPEN A_CUR   
FETCH NEXT FROM A_CUR INTO @D_ID, @D_SEV_ID, @D_U_KEY    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TblFinal(NOLOCK) WHERE F_U_KEY = @D_U_KEY AND F_IS_CLEAR = 0 AND F_SEV_ID <> -11)
       BEGIN
            DECLARE @FId INT
            SELECT @FId = F_ID FROM #TblFinal(NOLOCK) WHERE F_U_KEY = @D_U_KEY AND F_IS_CLEAR = 0 AND F_SEV_ID <> -11
            --IF @D_SEV_ID != -11
            IF (@D_SEV_ID <> -11)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE #TblFinal
                SET F_COUNTER = F_COUNTER + 1 WHERE F_ID = @FId
            END
            --IF @D_SEV_ID = -11
            ELSE IF(@D_SEV_ID = -11)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #TblFinal (F_VAL, F_SEV_ID, F_U_KEY)
                SELECT  D_VAL, D_SEV_ID, D_U_KEY FROM #TblData(NOLOCK) WHERE D_ID =  @D_ID

                UPDATE #TblFinal
                SET F_IS_CLEAR = 1 WHERE F_ID = @FId
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'DO NOTHING'
            END
       END
       ELSE
       BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #TblFinal (F_VAL, F_SEV_ID, F_U_KEY)
            SELECT  D_VAL, D_SEV_ID, D_U_KEY FROM #TblData(NOLOCK) WHERE D_ID =  @D_ID
       END

       FETCH NEXT FROM A_CUR INTO @D_ID, @D_SEV_ID, @D_U_KEY  
END   

CLOSE A_CUR   
DEALLOCATE A_CUR


--SELECT * FROM #TblData
SELECT * FROM #TblFinal
DROP TABLE #TblData
DROP TABLE #TblFinal
```

Comment: What is "huge data"? And what have you tried? Extra kudos for wanting to get rid of this cursor!!! I have to say those column names make me want to gouge my eyeballs out.

Comment: @Sean Lange, sorry for ugly column names

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? All the sample data looks like duplicates and it is really hard to decipher this. Also, why all the nolock hints? They don't provide any benefit as these are temp tables you created. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you insist on query hints you should use the WITH keyword, omitting it is deprecated.

Comment: I agree on nolock. It's correct that data are duplicates, that's why i took help for cursor. checking one record at a time and base on unique key check I decide update or insert. cursor code is self explanatory

Comment: I disagree that code is self explanatory. It is a bowl of pasta that I don't have an hour to unravel. You have 5 rows of input but only 4 after it executes. Why? One of the rows is missing from the output...which one is not there and why?

Comment: If you clearly observe"#TblData" table data, 2 [(1, 'test 1', 2, '1:100002135::::15124:9334'), (2, 'test 1', 2, '1:100002135::::15124:9334')] records are same (duplicate) on unique id "'1:100002135::::15124:9334'. hence cursor row by row processing add row first time and second time, update the counter. hope I explain it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121183/discussion-between-user584018-and-sean-lange).

Comment: Ahh...so you need the count of duplicates before and after a D_SEV_ID of -11 for each D_U_KEY? Can you have more than 1 -11 for each key?

Comment: ideally not, but need to take into consideration. probably I can add some sequence

Comment: but let's assume we don't have more than 1 -11 for each key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like a set-based approach will work for you since the order of your data looks important.  That said, there are some things you can do which should speed up your query by about 50%.

1. Loop from min(D_ID) to max(D_ID), incrementing by 1.
2. Only look for the item in #TblFinal once instead of once in an exists and then again to get the @FId.  Also, make sure #TblFinal has an index on F_U_KEY + F_IS_CLEAR + F_SEV_ID and that F_ID is either part of the clustered index or within an INCLUDE clause.  Ideally it is the first field in the clustered index for the updates to be fast.
3. By storing D_VAL in a variable, you can insert directly into #TblFinal from variables rather than having to SELECT again from #TblData.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @D_ID INT
DECLARE @FId INT
DECLARE @D_SEV_ID INT
DECLARE @D_U_KEY NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @D_VAL NVARCHAR(20)

DECLARE @Min_D_ID INT, @Max_D_ID INT
SELECT  @Min_D_ID = min(D_ID), @Max_D_ID = max(D_ID) FROM #TblData(NOLOCK)

SELECT @D_ID = @Min_D_ID

WHILE @D_ID <= @Max_D_ID
BEGIN   
    SELECT @D_SEV_ID = D_SEV_ID, @D_U_KEY = D_U_KEY, @D_VAL = D_VAL FROM #TblData(NOLOCK) WHERE D_ID = @D_ID

    IF @D_U_KEY IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @FId = F_ID FROM #TblFinal(NOLOCK) WHERE F_U_KEY = @D_U_KEY AND F_IS_CLEAR = 0 AND F_SEV_ID <> -11

        IF @FId IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF (@D_SEV_ID <> -11)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE #TblFinal
                SET F_COUNTER = F_COUNTER + 1 WHERE F_ID = @FId
            END
            ELSE IF(@D_SEV_ID = -11)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #TblFinal (F_VAL, F_SEV_ID, F_U_KEY)
                SELECT  @D_VAL, @D_SEV_ID, @D_U_KEY

                UPDATE #TblFinal
                SET F_IS_CLEAR = 1 WHERE F_ID = @FId
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'DO NOTHING'
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #TblFinal (F_VAL, F_SEV_ID, F_U_KEY)
            SELECT  @D_VAL, @D_SEV_ID, @D_U_KEY
        END
    END

    SELECT @D_ID = @D_ID + 1, @FId = NULL
END
```

Comment: gr8 suggesion. order of the data is very  important. Thanks for code, but output is not matching with my cursor result set.

Comment: Edited.  Set @FId back to NULL at end of loop.

Comment: Could you mark it as the answer, please?  I tested the set-based solution proposed by Sean but found that, as written, it didn't work if there were already rows in the final table.

Comment: Yes correct, but at least he provide a way to think on that line

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this set based. Here is one way to tackle this problem. The only part I don't really understand is F_IS_CLEAR. The business rule for that is a bit fuzzy. If you need help with part I need to understand what the rationale is for that.

```
CREATE TABLE #Output
(F_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), F_VAL NVARCHAR(20), F_SEV_ID INT, F_U_KEY NVARCHAR(200), F_COUNTER INT DEFAULT(1), F_IS_CLEAR BIT DEFAULT(0))

insert #Output
    select x.D_VAL
    , x.D_SEV_ID
    , x.D_U_KEY
    , x.F_COUNTER
    , x.F_IS_CLEAR
from 
(
    select D_VAL = MIN(D_VAL)
        , D_SEV_ID = MIN(D_SEV_ID)
        , D_U_KEY
        , F_COUNTER = COUNT(*)
        , F_IS_CLEAR = 1
        , SortOrder = 1
    from #TblData d
    where D_ID < (select d2.D_ID from #TblData d2 where d2.D_U_KEY = d.D_U_KEY and d2.D_SEV_ID = -11)
    group by d.D_U_KEY

    UNION ALL

    select D_VAL
        , D_SEV_ID
        , D_U_KEY
        , F_COUNTER = 1
        , F_IS_CLEAR = 0
        , SortOrder = 2
    from #TblData d
    where d.D_SEV_ID = -11

    UNION ALL

    select D_VAL = MIN(D_VAL)
        , D_SEV_ID = MIN(D_SEV_ID)
        , D_U_KEY
        , F_COUNTER = COUNT(*)
        , F_IS_CLEAR = 0
        , SortOrder = 3
    from #TblData d
    where D_ID > (select d2.D_ID from #TblData d2 where d2.D_U_KEY = d.D_U_KEY and d2.D_SEV_ID = -11)
    group by d.D_U_KEY

    UNION ALL

    select D_VAL = MIN(D_VAL)
        , D_SEV_ID = MIN(D_SEV_ID)
        , D_U_KEY
        , F_COUNTER = COUNT(*)
        , F_IS_CLEAR = 0
        , SortOrder = 4
    from #TblData d
    where NOT EXISTS (select d2.D_ID from #TblData d2 where d2.D_U_KEY = d.D_U_KEY and d2.D_SEV_ID = -11)
    group by d.D_U_KEY
) x

order by D_U_KEY, SortOrder

select * from #Output
```

Comment: amazing, thank u,could you please explain the code bit more

Comment: Sure. I just broke this into 4 pieces. First are the rows before a status of -11. Then the explicit -11. Third chunk is any rows after a status -11. Last but not least are those keys that don't have a status of -11. Then to get the data back out in the right order I included a column for sorting in each of those queries. Are there any pieces of this you still don't understand?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have problem with code for section SortOrder = 1 where we set F_IS_CLEAR = 1. If we don' have -11 for any key, then this is not applicable

Comment: OK, we're checking for "and d2.D_SEV_ID = -11", Thanks!

Comment: i will check with different combination of data and let know, thanks much again!!!!